# Stripe js UI not showing on IOS PWA

Tags: php, stripe-payments, progressive-web-apps

I have used pwa builder to create an iOS app.  Everything works perfect except for the Stripe UI on the credit card form.  On the app it shows a blank input field but when viewed in Chrome, Safari etc it shows the correct placeholder (ie. Card Number     MM/YYY).

I've tried changing the manifest.json display option from standalone to fullscreen (as suggested https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout-components/issues/699) but no luck.

I also tinkered with the stripe-charge.js script src link incase there was an issue with that when in the PWA shell but hasn't made a difference.

No js errors appear when viewing on browser so assuming it has something to do with what iOS does pulling a website into an app frame.

```
               <div id='card-element'>
                 <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
               </div>
               <!-- Used to display form errors -->
               <div id='card-errors'></div>
           </div>
           <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail' value='<? echo $user_email; ?>' />
           <button name='payment-form' class='cta_std__v4 _std__black'>Complete</button>
       </form>
       <script src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>
       <script src='/public/_asset/_js/stripe-charge.js'></script>
```

Comment: I'd ask support@stripe.com about this. It's their code, not yours.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your web app?

Comment: Okay fixed.  I need to add the following into the config.xml file:

<allow-navigation hap-rule="yes" href="https://js.stripe.com/v3/*" />
<allow-navigation hap-rule="yes" href="https://js.stripe.com/v2/*" />

Comment: @LukeHampshire: thanks this worked for me. You should post it as answer